# Laravel notifications (Get details on one single click)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, notifications

Building a Laravel App, where there will be lots of businesses listed for free. So my question is, if the frot-end user wants to contact a particular business, the admin of the site(i.e., ME) should receive the notification,

"ABC user" has asked to **arrange a call** for "XYZ Industries"

Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/k497wx
[image]

Comment: ok. so what you should you need?

Comment: What do you need? What type of notification are you talking about, email, push up? What have you tried?

Comment: try this https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/notifications

Comment: What I need is, how should I receive an email with the details of both sides, 'The USER (one who wants to arrange a call)' & 'The business person (The one to be contacted)'... In short, As soon as the user clicks on 'arrange a call', I should receive an email like this  --  "ABC user" has asked to arrange a call for "XYZ Industries"

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more code for the more detailed answer.

Let's say your Businesses are listed under `App\Business` model

Simplest thing to do would be, first create an Email Class:

In terminal: `php artisan make:mail NotifyMeOfBusinessCreated`

Then create a view in `emails\notify_me_of_business_created.blade.php`

Next in `NotifyMeOfBusinessCreated.php` add `use $business;` to the body of the class.

Your construct method should look like

```
public function __construct($business)
{
    $this->business = $business;
}
```

Your build method should look like

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('me@mydomain.com')
        ->view('emails.notify_me_of_business_created')
        ->subject('New business added');
}
```

Your `emails/notify_me_of_business_created.blade.php` should be something like

```
{{ $business->name }} created.
```

And finally in your `AppServiceProvider.php` add:

```
use App\Business;

....

public function boot() {
  Business::created(function ($business) {
     Mail:to('me@mydomain.com')->send(new NotifyMeOfBusinessCreated($business))
  });

  ...
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to get downvotes always add what you have tried so far and share relevant parts of your code.

Comment: Thanks @brnd0, but I already have this notification if new business is created, I just want to receive an email when a USER wants to be CONTACTED from a particular BUSINESS, its not about creating a new business, businesses are already been created.

Comment: I will keep this thing in mind :)  (If you don't want to get downvotes always add what you have tried so far and share relevant parts of your code.) Thanks

Comment: I could have sworn the original question was about notification when business is created. Anyhow, then just create a new route/controller/method, ping it when user clicks on that button, and in that method send an email.